# is there any method convert mutiple params to one bytes in web3js ,and then get these original data from bytes in solidity?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs

eg:
the params in js code below,how to convert to one bytes

```
var min=100;
var max=100000000000;
var price=1000000000000000000000000000;
var name="john";
```

in solidity code below,how to get original data from bytes

```
function test(bytes _data)public{
uint min=...
uint max=...
string name=...
}
```

Comment: web3js v0.x or v1.x?

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do it..

You can use [`ethereumjs-abi`](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi) in the client side to encode your message

```
  const abi = require('ethereumjs-abi');

  const params = [
    12345678,
    "0x00000000000000000000000000000000053eE86b",
    "hello"
  ];

  const message = `0x${abi.simpleEncode('parser(uint256,address,string)', ...params).toString('hex')}`;

  console.log(`Message: ${message}`);

  const res = await recipient.methods.test(message)
  .send({
    from: accounts[0],
  });
```

For the EVM side you can leverage on [Poor man's decodeABI trick](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/9p9rcd/poor_mans_decodeabi_in_solidity/). In the article they use `call` opcode but if you use `delegatecall` instead you will preserve `msg.sender`.

```
contract ParserDemo {
  uint public min;
  address public who;
  string public message;
  event Parsed(uint _min, address _who, string _message);
  event Data(bytes _message);
  function test(bytes data) public {
    address a = this;
    assembly {
      if iszero(delegatecall(gas, a, add(data, 32), mload(data), 0, 0)) {
          revert(0, 0)
      }
    }
  }
  function parser(uint _min, address _who, string _message) public {
    min = _min;
    who = _who;
    message = _message;
    emit Parsed(_min, _who, _message);
  }

}
```

An important difference with your question is the message has embedded the signature of the `parser()` function.